# How to query in sequelize by an association without loading the associated object?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have multiple models which are associated to each other.

e.g:

```
var User = sequelize.define("user")
var Project = sequelize.define("project")

Project.hasMany(User)
```

Now I want to query all Projects containing a specific user.

e.g.:

```
Project.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: User,
            where: { id }
        }
    ]
})
```

This works, but loads also the user and attaches it to the project.
How can I tell sequelize, that the user should not be added to the found projects?

Comment: Is this a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: yes it is a many to many relationship

Answer (score 4):

I just managed to address the same problem (using Sequelize 4).

You can specify that you don't want any fields of User just using `attributes: []`, so your code would become:

```
Project.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            attributes: [],
            model: User,
            where: { id }
        }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Many-to-many relationships are defined using the belongsToMany() method in sequelize on both sides. For your specific use case you would have to use a through model for the relation and query the through model directly.

```
var User = sequelize.define("user")
var Project = sequelize.define("project")
var ProjectUser = sequelize.define("projectUser")

Project.belongsToMany(User, {
    through: ProjectUser
})

User.belongsToMany(Project, {
    through ProjectUser
});

ProjectUser.findAll({
    where: {
        UserId: 'someId'
    },
    // We only want the project, not the user.
    // You might need to do ProjectUser.belongsTo() for both
    // models for this to work.
    include: [Project]
})
.then(function(results) {
    // Here we are getting an array of ProjectUsers, to return all the projects
    // we map it to a new array of only projects.
    return results.map(function(userProject) {
        return userProject.Project;
    });
})
```

Comment: this is not what I ment.
Event though it solves the problem in my example, which was just to simplify my problem. Actually I have the findAll with three nested including models, where I cannot use this approach.

Comment: Then I think the only way to do it is the one you're using. The only thing that I can think of is to specify which fields to get and only get the specific ID field you are using to look up, the model would still be included but only one field in it. That should speed the query up a lot.

Comment: The best way though is to use sequelize.query() and write the query manually.